# Unit testing a method that iterates through loops

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am trying to come up with a good way to test a method that goes through some loops and then gets an object and calls one of its methods.  That class has its own tests so I'm not sure exactly what to test here. I have written it to have different behavior in the test case, which is obviously not ideal.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to improve this to test without the conditionals.

```
def direct(self, test=False):
    """
    routes data in self.data_groups to
    consumers in self.consumers_list
    """
    if test:
        output_list = []
    for data_type, group in self.data_groups.items():
        if test:
            output_list.append(data_type)
            output_list.append(group)
        for consumer_name in self.consumers_list[data_type]:
            for record in group:
                if test:
                    output_list.append(record.values()[0])
                else:
                    consumer = self.get_consumer(consumer_name,
                                                 record)
                    consumer_output = consumer.do_something()

    if test:
        return output_list
    return True
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test for here?  In your tests you just have a list of items; is this all you want?  Why do you need to test that?  What benefit do you gain by having this test?

Comment: @Dannnno I am writing unit tests for every method in every class.  The question was migrated from codereview (I'm not sure why), and was about a better way to test the method.  The benefit is having good test coverage, as well as checking that the method does what it should.

Comment: I know, I saw the question on CR.  Don't pursue coverage for the sake of coverage - if it doesn't give you anything tangible then it doesn't help you.  You mentioned that you already have unit tests for the class - does that mean that things like `self.get_consumer(consumer_name, record)` are already well tested?  Writing tests to handle this really depends on which parts of it matter, and which parts we can ignore.

Comment: Yes, all the other methods are well tested.  Having good coverage improves the project in my opinion.  I think the test case I have is acceptable in terms of testing that the loops are doing what I expect but don't like the 'ifs'.  Do you know why the question was migrated?

Comment: So you're just trying to test that the iteration is working properly?  I don't, however if I had to guess it's because you're asking for test cases for your code, not for a review of the class.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I'm not sure that what you are talking about is possible. I'd say you could use a decorator but that'd be useless without overriding direct completely. I'm not sure if this is any better for you but you could just override the method for your tests in its own class? This would make it look a lot cleaner and you could group your code in a more intuitive way.

do something like:

```
class DirectClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data_groups = dict
        self.consumers_list = list

    def direct(self):
        """
        routes data in self.data_groups to
        consumers in self.consumers_list
        """
        for data_type, group in self.data_groups.items():
            for consumer_name in self.consumers_list[data_type]:
                for record in group:
                    consumer = self.get_consumer(consumer_name,
                                                 record)
                    consumer_output = consumer.do_something()

        return True

class TestDirect(DirectClass):
    def __init__(self):
        DirectClass.__init__(self)

    def direct(self):
        output_list = []
        for data_type, group in self.data_groups.items():
            output_list.append(data_type)
            output_list.append(group)
            for consumer_name in self.consumers_list[data_type]:
                for record in group:
                    output_list.append(record.values()[0])

        return output_list
```

Answer (score 1):

I settled on sub-classing the object returned by consumer so that I could call the same code and have the over-ridden run (formerly do_something) method return test data.  There are still more ifs than I want but it achieves most of my objective.  Credit to @user2916286 for getting me thinking about subclassing in this case.

```
def direct(self, test=False):
    """
    routes data in self.data_groups to
    consumers in self.consumers_list
    """
    if test:
        output_list = []
    for data_type, group in self.data_groups.items():
        if test:
            output_list.append(data_type)
            output_list.append(group)
        for consumer_name in self.consumers_list[data_type]:
            for record in group:
                consumer = self.get_consumer(consumer_name,
                                             record, test=test)
                consumer_output = consumer.run()
                if not consumer_output:
                    raise Exception('consumer failed')
                output_list.append(consumer_output)
    if test:
        return output_list
    return True
```